# python for loop in matrix to assign values

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, matrix

I was creating a program that will create a grid and the program will
deside its position by a matrix array you assign at the input.

code:

```
def onbekende_naam(hoogtes):
    print(hoogtes)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    pos1 = set()

    for hoogtes_subs in hoogtes:
        j = 0
        for hoogtes in hoogtes:
            print("i = " + str(i))
            print("j = " + str(j))
            pos1.add((i, j))
            print pos1
            j += 1
        i += 1
        #pos1.add((i, j))

    return pos1

#verwerking
print (onbekende_naam(hoogtes))
```

input:

```
4 4
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
12 1
```

output:

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['5', '6', '7', '8'], ['9', '1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6', '7']]
i = 0
j = 0
set([(0, 0)])
i = 0
j = 1
set([(0, 1), (0, 0)])
i = 0
j = 2
set([(0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 2)])
i = 0
j = 3
set([(0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 0), (0, 2)])
i = 1
j = 0
set([(0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0)])
i = 1
j = 1
set([(0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (0, 3), (1, 1)])
i = 1
j = 2
set([(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (0, 3), (1, 1)])
i = 1
j = 3
set([(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 3), (1, 0), (0, 3), (1, 1)])
i = 2
j = 0
set([(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (1, 3), (1, 0), (0, 3), (1, 1)])
i = 3
j = 0
set([(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 0), (3, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (1, 3), (1, 0), (0, 3), (1, 1)])
set([(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 0), (3, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (1, 3), (1, 0), (0, 3), (1, 1)])
```

as you can see it stops incrementing j when the i value is bigger than 2

I'm fairly new at this so thanks for helping

Comment: Please include the code _as formatted text_ in your question and make sure it's a [mcve].

Comment: Ha, kan je je code normaal copy pasten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you use the same name in your second for loop. Can you try if changing this works?

```
def onbekende_naam(hoogtes):
    print(hoogtes)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    pos1 = set()

    for hoogtes_subs in hoogtes:
        j = 0
        for another_name_hoogtes in hoogtes:
            print("i = " + str(i))
            print("j = " + str(j))
            pos1.add((i, j))
            print pos1
            j += 1
        i += 1
        #pos1.add((i, j))

    return pos1

#verwerking
print (onbekende_naam(hoogtes))
```

Also: when I run your original code I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Why didn't you get this error?

Comment: Look at my edit. You are not even using the values in the array. Anyways: do not use duplicate variable names in the future ;)

Comment: Thank you so much.
I've had this error before and fixed it.
But it totaly went unoticed this time.
(on my first comment i was looking at your code not the original that was where my confusion was coming from)

Comment: Great. Good luck with your project.